# For and foreach loop are not prforming all iterations in my razor page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

So I have data in my `ViewBag` and I am trying to print in the data table in my View. When the count was 8488 then both loops are skipping the last 20 records (printing only 8466 records). loops are exiting without any error.
Then I have updated records. Now I have 8502 counts in my `ViewBag` but the loop is exiting after 8480 records.

```
try
{
    int count = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.allusers.Count; i++)
    {
        var item = ViewBag.allusers[i];
        var date = "none";
        var time = "none";
        var contractor = "none";
        var areakey = "none";
        var ReportStatus = 0;
        var division = "none";
        if (item.SubmissionDate != null)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(item.SubmissionDate).Split(' ')[0] == Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today).Split(' ')[0])
            {
                date = Convert.ToString(item.SubmissionDate).Split(' ')[0];
                DateTime newdate = item.SubmissionDate;
                date = newdate.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                time = Convert.ToString(item.SubmissionDate).Split(' ')[1];
                division = item.UDFDivision;
                areakey = item.AreKey;
                ReportStatus = 1;
                contractor = item.UDFContractor;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        <tr>
            <td>@item.FName</td>
            <td>@item.LName</td>
            <td>@item.UDFContractor</td>
            <td>@item.UDFDivision</td>
            <td>@item.AreKey</td>
            @if (item.SubmissionDate != null)
            {
                <td>Yes</td>
            }
            else
            {
                <td>No</td>
            }
        @if (ReportStatus != 0 && item.ReportStatus)
            {
                <td style="color:green;">Positive</td>
            }
            else if (ReportStatus != 0 && !item.ReportStatus)
            {
                <td style="color:red;">Negative</td>
            }
        else
        {
                <td>none</td>
            }
            <td>@date</td>
            <td>@time</td>
            @{
            string cdate = DateTime.Now.Date.ToString();
                <td>@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</td>
            }
            <td>@item.PublicID</td>
        </tr>
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: I see a `continue` - are the missing ones hitting that? (`continue` means "go to the next item" in this context)

Comment: O.T.: Is `item.SubmissionDate` a `DateTime` (or `Nullable<DateTime>`)? In such case, please avoid converting the value to string (moreover without culture specification) to get what is already exposed by properties ([DateTime struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime))!!!   and cache `DateTime.Now` in a local variable before the loop to avoid recomputing at each iteration both `DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.Today` (one calls the other).